# How to Change Interval Time Dynamically in For Loop According to Index/iteration Number?

Tags: javascript, wait

Since I could not comment, I am forced to write this post. I got the below code  which delays/waits exactly 1 seconds or 1000 milliseconds -

```js
let n = 5;
for (let i=1; i<n; i++)
{
  setTimeout( function timer()
  {
      console.log("hello world");
  }, i*1000 );
}
```

But how can I delay it i*1000 seconds instead of fixed 1000 milliseconds so the waiting depends on iteration number ?

**For example, if n= 5 , then I want the loop delay 1 second in 1st iteration. 2 seconds in second iteration, and so on.. the final delay will 5 seconds.**

Comment: So you want to make 9 timers? If so, then your code will do what you are asking. It does not wait exactly 3 seconds. In fact, timers will never be exact.

Comment: @ScottMarcus , not clear what you are saying , 10 is just an example

Comment: I'm asking how many timers you want to make.... Why the loop?

Comment: The code that you wrote isn't working?

Comment: how many times do you want to alert "hello world"?

Comment: your question makes no sense

Comment: Just tried your code out in a codepen: https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/BaaBMwW You get 9 messages 3000ms apart - if that's not what you want (but from your question it does sound like it is), please specify what your intended result is.

Comment: setTimeout will call asynchronously the function supplied to it after the timeout and this will not block the iteration of the loop. Looks like you are trying to assume that it will work synchronously for each iteration.

Comment: @pavanskipo in each iteration

Comment: You don’t seem to understand how setTimeout works in the first place - it is **not** a “delay”. Right now, you are getting your alerts in 3 second intervals, _because_ you already multiplied the 3000 with `i` - if you didn’t do that, then you would get all those alerts at the _same_ time.

Comment: *Request to all: Plz chk the post again, I added an example below*

Comment: Editing the question in order to make your last sentence bold is not really helping your case. You have now been told by multiple commentators that your code already does what you're asking for (or rather, it's not quite clear what you are ACTUALLY asking for, if that's not your intended result).

Comment: @ConstantinGroß plz chk the below part of the post again plz

Comment: Also use console.log since alert will block the timeout

Comment: @ConstantinGroß no it does not, have tried?

Comment: All those `setTimeout` calls are happening at the same time (well one after the other, but within a matter of mere milliseconds at most.) If you want to see your first alert after one second, and the next one two seconds _after that_ - then your setTimeout call for that second one must use a value of _three_ seconds, not two. And so one for all the following ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a function that will show immediately, then 1 second later, 2 seconds after than, 3 seconds after that etc. No special math, no promises needed

```js
const n = 5;
let cnt=0;

function show() {
  console.log("call "+cnt,"delay: ",cnt,"sec");
  cnt++;
  if (cnt > n) return; // we are done
  setTimeout(show, cnt*1000 ); // cnt seconds later
}
show()
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry that I missed your answer, there were so many comments, misunderstanding, answers... anyway I am choosing your answer as you were first one who solved what I asked thanks for your time sir.

Comment: @Mike Lol. The other solutions are useful in their own right, so thanks for the accept

Comment: Pavan's is the same in ES6 syntax. Harder to read but it is in fact the same. His edit to make it so was made at the same time as I wrote mine :)

Answer (score 9):

While this task could be solved with promises, reactive streams and other cool tools (hey, nobody has suggested using workers yet!), it can also be solved with a little arithmetics.

So you want timeouts in a sequence: 1s, the previous one + 2s, the previous one + 3s, and so on. This sequence is: 1, 3, 6, 10, 15... and its formula is `a[n] = n * (n + 1) / 2`. Knowing that...

```js
let n = 6;
console.log(new Date().getSeconds());

for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
  }, 1000 * i * (i + 1) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Mathematicians are still alive !! :)

Answer (score 5):

Took me some time to decipher your question xD, but is this what you want?

This will keep firing **console.log** with i*1000 delay each time.
so the first time it will be 1 second long (1*1000), next it will be 2 seconds and so on.

```js
let i = 0;
loop = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(new Date()); // for clarity
    i++;
    if (i < 10) {
      loop();
    }
  }, i * 1000)
};
loop();
```

Comment: For example, if n= 5 , then I want the loop delay 1 second in 1st iteration. 2 seconds in second iteration, and so on.. the final delay will 5 seconds.

Comment: yup this will delay 1 second for 1st iteration, 2 seconds for 2nd and so on, try it

Comment: Your description does not match the code. But it does the job

Answer (score 5):

You can try using async/await (Promises), to serialize your code:

```js
const waitSeconds = seconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds))

async function main () {
 let oldDate = new Date()
 let newDate
 
 /* 
  * If you put 'await' inside the loop you can synchronize the async code, and simulate
  * a sleep function
  */
 for (let i=1; i<5; i++) {
    await waitSeconds(i*1000)
    newDate = new Date()   
    console.log(`Loop for i=${i}, elapsed=${moment(newDate).diff(oldDate, 'seconds')} seconds`)
    oldDate = newDate
 }
 
 console.log('End')
}

main()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use recursive calls instead of for loop

```js
let i=1;
function a(i) {
  if (i > 5)
    return
  else
    b("message", i)
}

function b(s, f) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    console.log(s + " " + f + " seconds");
  }, f * 1000);
  a(++i);
}
a(i);
```

Comment: For example, if n= 5 , then I want the loop delay 1 second in 1st iteration. 2 seconds in second iteration, and so on.. the final delay will 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Loop doesn't waits for timeout function to be completed.
So, when the loop runs it schedules your alert for each index.

You can use a function which will run according to your index but scheduled at same time. You can feel the difference of 3 seconds.

```
function test(i){
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log("hello world" + i);
    }, i*3000);
}
for (let i=1; i<4; i++) {
   test(i);
}
```