# How to pass on dynamic delay to d3.interval

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**[d3.interval](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#interval)** takes two parameters, `callback and delay`,e.g.
`d3.interval(callback, delay)`.

I was wondering if it is possible to pass on a dynamic delay for each interval.

For example, in the following, I am asking the `interval` to run at `1000ms` delay. But is there a way I can ask `d3.interval` to run at `0ms, 1000ms, 2000ms, 3000ms` respectively for interval# `1,2,3,4`.

I tried like `desiredDelay[counterF]` but it did not work.

```js
const masterSelection = d3.selectAll('[class^="text"]');
const node = masterSelection.nodes();
const len = node.length - 1;
let counterF = 0;
const del = 1000;
const desiredDelay = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000]

let ticker = d3.interval(
    e => {
        const element = masterSelection['_groups'][0][counterF];
        const selection = d3.select(element).node();
        console.log(selection);
        counterF++;
        (counterF > len) ? ticker.stop(): null

    }, del
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div class='text1'>one</div>
    <div class='text2'>two</div>
    <div class='text3'>three</div>
    <div class='text4'>four</div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prod.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58236318/11156131), the following works as desired and is to be used with `d3.timeout`.

```js
const masterSelection = d3.selectAll('[class^="text"]');
const node = masterSelection.nodes();
const len = node.length - 1;
let counter = 0;
//const del = 1000;
const delay = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000];

function show() {

    const element = masterSelection["_groups"][0][counter];
    const selection = d3.select(element).node();
    console.log(selection);

    counter++;
    if (counter > len) return
    d3.timeout(show, delay[counter]);
}

show();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div class='text1'>one</div>
    <div class='text2'>two</div>
    <div class='text3'>three</div>
    <div class='text4'>four</div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/blob/main/src/interval.js) you'll see that if the delay is not `null`...

```
if (delay == null) return t.restart(callback, delay, time), t;
```

...it will be coerced to a number using the unary plus operator:

```
t.restart = function(callback, delay, time) {
    delay = +delay,
    etc...
```

What you can do is creating your own interval function, which is out of the scope of this answer.